# Apparatus for recieving Radiant Energy by Nikola Tesla

Tags: experimental-physics, cosmic-rays

http://www.keelynet.com/tesla/00685958.pdf

An elevated, insulated copper plate, a patented Tesla Condenser, and a voltage inverter, we've got free electricity right?

admittedly small, but as a proportion to potential difference in the height of the mast and possibly the depth of the ground pole.

Anyone really know what's going on here and why it's not implemented?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really cool patent you've dug up, especially considering the time-frame! Tesla is talking about the photoelectric effect. His first guess is wrong: the radiant rays themselves are not charged, but his second guess is closer - the rays enable a negatively charged metallic plate to throw off electrons, and thus discharge itself. This expulsion of electrons is also why the exposed plate tends to acquire a positive charge - not because the rays are bringing in positive charge, but because they help negative charge (electrons) escape.

According to wikipedia, by 1899 J.J. Thomson had shown that UV rays caused the emission of electrons (corpuscles). In 1902 Philipp Lenard's experiments showed the dependence of the electron kinetic energy on frequency, and by 1905 Einstein had revealed the underlying quantum physics.

I am not entirely sure what goes wrong with Tesla's power generation scheme. Certainly one issue is that as the exposed plate gives off more electrons, it becomes more positive (its electric potential rises) and it becomes harder for electrons to be ripped off by the photoelectric effect. The presence of the condenser (capacitor) may mitigate this somewhat, but in the end the capacitor dielectric will breakdown, or the exposed plate will become too positive to release further electrons. Further complications involve the fact that the photoelectric effect is best observed in a vacuum, where the metal surface of the exposed plate will be slow to oxidize. I suspect some combination of all these facts make solar cells more cost effective.

Comment: Serious question: Have you ever seen a Tesla paper with an equation?

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer Good question, it probably could have been good to do so, but dont forget that Tesla (like Edisson) were inventors (sth like saying they were experimentalists) and not theoretical physicists (which imo is not the determining factor in inventing sth that actually works)

Comment: @NikosM. You may be hurting a lot of experimentalists' feelings in saying they're something like inventors who don't use equations ;)

Comment: @Danu, ok, i certainly did not mean that, i just wanted to say that using equations is not the determining factor in making sth that atually works, of course many experimental physicists could as well be excellent theorists (for example Joos)